# PHP_XLSXWriter questions

Tags: php, excel-2007

I am using [PHP_XLSXWriter](https://github.com/mk-j/PHP_XLSXWriter). 
I want to do the following expected output:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
<?php
include_once('./PHP_XLSXWriter-master/xlsxwriter.class.php');

$writer = new XLSXWriter();
$sheet_name = 'Sheet1';

$header = array("A", "B", "C");

$writer->writeSheetRow($sheet_name, $header);

$writer->markMergedCell($sheet_name, $start_row = ?, $start_col = ?, $end_row = ?, $end_col = ?);

$writer->writeToFile('test.xlsx');
?>
```

How should control ? in my code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There can be better options to do this, but I could do only this kind of a workaround. It may be helpful for you.

```
<?php
include_once("xlsxwriter.class.php"); //include
$writer = new XLSXWriter();     //new writer
$sheet_name = 'sheets';   //sheetname
$header = array("string","string","string","string","string","string");  // header-made for six columns
$row1 = array("A"," ","B"," ","C"); //column B1, D1 made blank to match formatting
$writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet_name, $header, $suppress_header_row = true);   //write header
$writer->markMergedCell($sheet_name, $start_row = 0, $start_col = 0, $end_row = 1, $end_col = 1);  //merge cells for A
$writer->markMergedCell($sheet_name, $start_row = 0, $start_col = 2, $end_row = 0, $end_col = 3);  //merge cells for B
$writer->markMergedCell($sheet_name, $start_row = 0, $start_col = 4, $end_row = 0, $end_col = 5);  //merge cells for C
$writer->writeSheetRow($sheet_name, $row1);   //write data
$writer->writeToFile('test.xlsx');  //save file
?>
```

Edit: If you need looping for repeating same style of merging, do like this

```
<?php
include_once("xlsxwriter.class.php"); //include
$writer = new XLSXWriter();     //new writer
$sheet_name = 'sheets';   //sheetname
$header = array("string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string","string");  // header-made for 19 columns
$row1 = array("A"," ","B"," ","C"," ","D"," ","E"," ","F"," ","G"," ","H"," ","I"," ","J"); //column B1, D1, F1, H1, J1, L1, N1, P1, R1 made blank to match formatting
$writer->writeSheetHeader($sheet_name, $header, $suppress_header_row = true);   //write header
$writer->markMergedCell($sheet_name, $start_row = 0, $start_col = 0, $end_row = 1, $end_col = 1);  //merge cells for A
$j = 2; //start column
for ($i=0; $i<9; $i++)
{
$writer->markMergedCell($sheet_name, $start_row = 0, $start_col = $j, $end_row = 0, $end_col = $j+1);  //merge cells
$j+=2;
}
$writer->writeSheetRow($sheet_name, $row1);   //write data
$writer->writeToFile('test.xlsx');  //save file
?>
```

Comment: Nice...But if I have a row name from B to K, that means I need to write 10 seperate code for each of them? For loop cannot do this?

Comment: Row name or column name?? @KKLMichael

Comment: If every merging is same style, then you can use loop. if different kind of merging, you can use a loop. @KKLMichael

Comment: @KKLMichael : There is a edit, I think it will be helpful for you.

Comment: can you help with adding image to the sheet, please?